# Polymer Vulcanize CSS

Tags: polymer, content-security-policy, google-chrome-app

I am trying to package my Polymer web app as a Chrome Packaged App, but I am running into some issues surrounding Chrome's Content Security Policy (CSP). I am vulcanizing the app (with the `--csp` option) before packaging it, which works great for the JavaScript portion, but fails to extract the CSS inlined in Polymer's elements. Is there any way to either 1) override the CSP for Polymer's CSS or 2) extract the CSS and place it in a separate file for all Polymer elements?

As far as I can tell, there is a PR in the works to resolve this issue, but it hasn't been updated since August: https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize/pull/33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gulp-cssmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssmin) to concatenate your css extracted from inline htmls with vulcanize --csp option.

See example of clean-css in [Github](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) page:

```
type one.css two.css three.css | cleancss -o merged-and-minified.css
```